# How to remove part of a line in linux?

Tags: linux

Say I have file like this

```
username:::
username2:56+4564894765:usersfsmas:fdggfdgd:
username3:::
username4:::
```

I want to return a username on random without the ':'. To note, a username cant have ':' on it and after the first ':' there could be any character

so basically I want

```
$ ./getRandom file
username

$ ./getRandom file
username3
```

I think I could grep with some regex in it not sure how to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just the usernames, `cut -d: -f1`

To get a random line, use `shuf -n 1`

So:

```
cut -d: -f1 file | shuf -n 1
```